# Quick Sort Algorithm doesnt print anything on console nor shows anything in Debug

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

The question essentially describes it all. I am implementing quicksort on my own and I am stuck as nothing is shown on debug and nothing prints on console. I feel my implementation is incorrect but don't know where I am going wrong.

Please note, this is not a assignment or a homework. I am learning sorting algorithms and this is the most efficient one.

Here is my code:

public class QuickSort {

```
static void swap(Integer[] arr, int i, int j)
{
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;

}
static int partition(Integer[] arr, int min, int max)
{
    int pivot = min;
    int i=min+1,j=max;

    while(i < j)
    {
        if(arr[i] > arr[pivot] && arr[pivot] < arr[j])
        {
            swap(arr, arr[i], arr[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
static void sort(Integer[] arr, int min, int max)
{

    if(min < max)
    {
        int partitionInd = partition(arr, min, max);
        System.out.print(partitionInd);
        sort(arr, min,partitionInd-1 );
        sort(arr, partitionInd+1, max);
    }


}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Integer inputArray[] = new Integer[]{5,2,7,4,9,1,3};
    sort(inputArray, 0, inputArray.length - 1);

    for(int i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++)
    {
    System.out.print(inputArray[i] + "\t");
        }

}
```

}

Comment: What is "nothing is shown on debug" mean? It sounds like you seriously don't know how to debug, or you're talking about print statements, which are probably in the wrong place then and/or you should make that `println` - output tends to only get flushed (read - displayed) once it gets a line break.

Comment: Why don't you drop in a load of System.out.println() calls and print the state at various places. It should help you follow what's going on or going wrong.

Comment: I added a breakpoint at the sort function and went to debug. I am new to using the debug but can you help @Dukeling

Comment: As you mentioned having print statements at the wrong place.. can you please tell me what is the right place then? @Dukeling

Comment: You could put one before every if statement, at the beginning of every function and loop, print out the values of any variable whenever it changes. You can just start with a few and add more, or start with mass-loads of them, and remove some to eliminate possible problematic areas, until you find the problem. It's not an exact science, and many people will probably tell you to learn to debug first / instead (I can't really offer much advice there - I find debugging pretty intuitive, and I happily switch between them as desired). I'm assuming you've changed `print` to `println` as I mentioned?

Comment: I changed `print` to `println` but still nothing printing on console nor I can see anything in `debug`

Comment: Your println is after the infinite loop. Look at the partition while loop when the if condition evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will discuss the problems in your algorithm, which are in the `partition` method:

**1.** You are incrementing/decrementing your variables `i` and `j` only if the both conditions `arr[i] > arr[pivot] && arr[pivot] < arr[j]` are fulfilled. If they are not, you end up in an endless `while`, because `i` is smaller than `j` but the condition in the `if` is not fulfilled so you never increment/decrement both variables.

**2.** Your checks in the condition `arr[i] > arr[pivot] && arr[pivot] < arr[j]` are wrong. You simple check if both of the elements with the indexes `i` and `j` are bigger than the element with index `pivot`, which is wrong. For the `i` index you should check if it is smaller, because it should increment while it founds an element, which is bigger or equal to the element with index `pivot`.

**3.** You are incrementing/decrementing the variables only once, which means, that you sometimes swap elements, which are not supposed to be swapped, cause the idea is that the index `i` should find an index, where the element is bigger or equal of the element with the `pivot` index and j should find an element, which is smaller equal. You are not supposed to swap earlier, so you basically need to add more loops and swap only if `i<j`.

**4.** At the end of the partition, you put the pivot element on it's right place, by swapping with element at position `i-1` cause `i` is outOfBounds/bigger than the pivot element.

Here is the fixed algorithm, I suggest you to examine it well and re-read your theory.

```
static int partition(Integer[] arr, int min, int max) {
   int pivot = min;
   int i = min + 1, j = max;

   while (i < j) {
       while (i < arr.length && arr[i] < arr[pivot]) {
           ++i;
       }

       while (j >= 0 && arr[pivot] < arr[j]) {
           --j;
       }

       if (i < j) {
           swap(arr, i, j);
       }

    }

    swap(arr, i - 1, pivot);

    return i;
}
```

It's a good idea to install an IDE such as Eclipse and learn how to debug with it. Here is an installation guide: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation You would need **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** IMO. Here is a guide how to debug with eclipse: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

And quicksort is not ultimately the best sorting algorithm. It depends on the situation. You should check Mergesort as well, as well as some other good sorting algorithms.